# Display Vector-based pdf's within a self-contained Android songbook app

Tags: android, pdf, vector

I want to create an Android version of an iOS songbook app titled ELS Hymnbook.

It displays vector based sheet music.  I am having trouble finding a way to display the PDF files in Android without using a 3rd party viewer.  Can Android display a pdf within the app based on a search result or song list selection?  We are working in conjunction with the iOS developer of this app. I do not want to use a web view - I want the app to be completely self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

There are [built-in APIs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/package-summary.html) to render PDFs

Comment: I believe that PDF Renderer is only available for Android 5.0 and up. Do you know of anything that is compatible with older versions of android?

Comment: You could look for some third-party library that can render PDFs on older devices. I don't know of any off-hand.